# What does $f([G,G]) \leq [H,H]$ mean in the case of commutators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> This motivates the definition of the commutator subgroup
>   $[G, G]$ (also called the derived subgroup, and denoted
>   $G'$ or $G^{(1)}$) of $G$: it is the subgroup
>   generated by all the commutators.
>
> It follows from the properties of commutators that any element of
>   $[G,G]$ is of the form
>
> $[g_1,h_1] \cdots [g_n,h_n]$
>
> for some natural number $n$.  Moreover, since $ ([g_1,h_1] \cdots [g_n,h_n])^s = [g_1^s,h_1^s] \cdots [g_n^s,h_n^s]$, the
>   commutator subgroup is normal in $G$.  For any homomorphism $f: G → H$,
>
> $ f([g_1,h_1] \cdots [g_n,h_n]) = [f(g_1),f(h_1)] \cdots [f(g_n),f(h_n)] $,
>
> so that $f([G,G]) \leq [H,H]$.

OK, I get how $[G,G]$ is constructed, and how $f([G,G])$ is constructed, but I am not sure what $f([G,G]) \leq [H,H]$ is. Is this saying that $f([G,G])$ has less elements than $[H,H]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $G \le H$ simply means that $G$ is a (not necessarily proper) 
**subgroup** of $H$.

Comment: This is to distinguish from $G \subseteq H$, which merely shows inclusion of sets.

Answer (score 0):

"Is this saying that $f([G,G])$ has less elements than $[H,H]$?" - Less or equal.